# How can a Warlord gain an at-will power that pushes?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

I know you can multiclass, but that gives you another class's at-will power as an encounter power.  I'm looking for an at-will attack that also pushes, but I'm playing a Warlord and they don't have any.

Is there any way I can get an at-will power that pushes at Heroic or low Paragon tier? How can I get a power from another class as an at-will power?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Warlords have Opening Shove (from the Martial Power book), which does, in fact, push.

Warlords who use a two-handed spear or polearm can also take the Longhand Student feat, which adds push 1 to Viper Strike. Warlords who use a greatbow or longbow can take the Adamant Arrow Student feat to add push 1 with Paint the Bullseye.

If none of those meet your needs, there are two ways for characters of any class to gain another class' at-will power. Both kick in at (or can kick in at) level 11, but also require a fair amount of investment.

**One: Be a Half-Elf**

Half-elves have the racial ability Dilettante, which lets them select an at-will power from another class and use it once per encounter. There is a paragon-tier feat, Versatile Master, that lets them use their Dilettante power at-will.

**Two: Paragon Multi-class**

If a character of class A multi-classes into class B, and has taken the encounter, daily, & utility power swap feats by level 10, then at level 11 they can choose to paragon multi-class (PMC) in class B *instead of* choosing a paragon path. Among other things, this allows them to, at level 11, replace one of their two class A at-wills with an at-will from class B.

Comment: I have contemplated opening shove, but that allows for an ally to make the attack. I was looking for an attack which I can make myself so I didn't have to worry about pushing the enemy next to an ally to do damage. I am approaching paragon and want to take polearm gamble and heavy blade opportunity to go with my glaive, to constantly repel anyone who stands next to me.

Comment: @ToddTabacco: Opening Shove can actually work quite well if you grab some feats/items to increase the push distance (Rushing Cleats & Spear Push spring to mind); combine with Polearm Momentum and you can place any enemy that approaches you prone at your striker's feat along with a free attack.

Comment: @ToddTabacco: Also, you'll want to actually stop their movement somehow. If you push them and they still have movement left, they can keep moving after the push and still end adjacent to you. You want some way to prone/slow/immobilize on push as well (like the previously mentioned Polearm Momentum).

Comment: Thanks for the advice on searching push feats. Looks like if I take the Longhand student feat, it adds a push to Viper Strike, which give me a damage attack on the OA with a push and then if the enemy shifts my ally gets an another attack also...I think it may be the way to go.